# Why doesn't mix-manifest.json refresh?

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, manifest, laravel-mix

My `webpack.mix.js`

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.scripts([
    'node_modules/highlightjs/highlight.pack.js',
    'public/js/app.js'
], 'public/js/app.js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.copy('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts')
.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.version();
```

The `version()` method was obviously used but `mix-manifest.json` file wasn't refreshed.

mix repeatedly returns the same `mix-manifest.json` file.

```
{
  "/js/app.js": "/js/app.29dc49fed41329db45585945297fcf3e.js",
  "/css/app.css": "/css/app.42b000e5046630edd233b0eb8d2df902.css"
}
```

How can I refresh that?

Answer (score 2):

The version number will only change if the file being saved is different from the currently versioned file.

Try making a minor change to your app.scss file and you will see the version number update.

Comment: 'app.css' file version was changed when changeed app.scss but even though changed 'resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js' file version wasn't changed